# extract alt-tag with Xpath & Python

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract the 'alt' tag of the images in the code block below, **where class of the surrounding div is 'onIcon'.** (example = Modelcontract or Kabeltelevisie)

```html
<tbody>
 <tr class="odd"><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Modelcontract"><a href="/nl/modelcontract"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_modelcontract_on.png" alt="Modelcontract" /></a></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Kamer"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_room_on.png" alt="Kamer" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Studio"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_studio_off.png" alt="Studio" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Appartement"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_apartment_off.png" alt="Appartement" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Internet"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_internet_on.png" alt="Internet" /></div></td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Kabeltelevisie"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_cable_tv_on.png" alt="Kabeltelevisie" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Gemeenschappelijke leefruimte"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_shared_living_space_on.png" alt="Gemeenschappelijke leefruimte" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Tuin/terras"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_garden_on.png" alt="Tuin/terras" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Fietsenstalling"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_bicycle_shed_on.png" alt="Fietsenstalling" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Beddengoed"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_bedding_off.png" alt="Beddengoed" /></div></td> </tr>
 <tr class="odd"><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Keukengerei"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_kitchen_utensils_on.png" alt="Keukengerei" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Muziekinstrumenten toegelaten"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_musical_instruments_allowed_off.png" alt="Muziekinstrumenten toegelaten" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Roken niet toegelaten"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_smoking_allowed_off.png" alt="Roken niet toegelaten" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Huisdieren wel/niet toegelaten"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_animals_allowed_off.png" alt="Huisdieren wel/niet toegelaten" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Bemeubeld"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_furnished_off.png" alt="Bemeubeld" /></div></td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Toegankelijk voor rolstoelgebruikers"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_wheelchair_accssible_off.png" alt="Toegankelijk voor rolstoelgebruikers" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Geschikt voor allergiepatienten"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_allergies_off.png" alt="Geschikt voor allergiepatienten" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Verhuur aan niet-studenten"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_non_students_off.png" alt="Verhuur aan niet-studenten" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon offIcon Straatkant"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_street_off.png" alt="Straatkant" /></div></td><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Niet aan straatkant"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_notstreet_on.png" alt="Niet aan straatkant" /></div></td> </tr>
 <tr class="odd"><td><div class="roomdetail_icon onIcon Building regulations"><img src="/sites/all/themes/kotweb/images/icons/grid/grid_building_regulations_on.png" alt="Building regulations" /></div></td> </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using XPath with Python and had gotten to the following query:

```
'features': response.xpath("//div[@class='onIcon']//img/@alt").extract()
```

Unfortunately this returns an empty array([]).

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now: what am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.xpath("//div[@class[contains(., 'onIcon')]]//img/@alt")
```

the class's value is `roomdetail_icon onIcon Modelcontract`, not just `onIcon`, you should use `contains` function

`.` means current context node (@class).

out:

```
['Modelcontract',
 'Kamer',
 'Internet',
 'Kabeltelevisie',
 'Gemeenschappelijke leefruimte',
 'Tuin/terras',
 'Fietsenstalling',
 'Keukengerei',
 'Niet aan straatkant',
 'Building regulations']
```

Each time you do `[@class='onIcon']`, xpath will go though some steps:

1. XPath notice there is string `'onIcon'`, so it will convert `@class` to string, in that case those two can be compared.
2. In order to convert `@class` to string, there is a `string()` function and  `string(@class)` will return the class's value `roomdetail_icon onIcon Modelcontract`
3. Finally, XPath compares `['roomdetail_icon onIcon Modelcontract'='onIcon']`

Comment: Thanks so much, this sorted it out! 

I was confused by the @class definition from XPath

Comment: @Thomas Blomme I added some explain, and please accept the answer to close this question.